# No instance returned Zend Framework 2?

Tags: zend-framework2, instance, adapter, cpanel

I have developed one project and successfully works on my local machine.on live site i create one folder dev in public_html and move same project from local machine,but  its gives me following error.

> Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotCreatedException

```
File: /home/projectname/public_html/dev/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:859
Message: An exception was raised while creating "Front/Model/Slider"; no instance returned
```

> Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotCreatedException

```
File: /home/projectname/public_html/dev/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:859
Message: An exception was raised while creating "Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter"; no instance returned
```

> Zend\Db\Adapter\Exception\RuntimeException

```
File: /home/projectname/public_html/dev/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Driver/Pdo/Pdo.php:218
Message: The PDO extension is required for this adapter but the extension is not loaded..
```

My Service Factory means model.config.php file is:

```
<?php
    namespace Front;
    /*use Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager;*/
    class Module
    {
        public function getAutoloaderConfig()
        {
            return array('Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' =>
                array('namespaces' =>
                    array(__NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,),
                ),
            );
        }
    /*    public function init(ModuleManager $moduleManager)
        {
            $sharedEvents = $moduleManager->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();
            $sharedEvents->attach(__NAMESPACE__, 'dispatch', function($e) {
                // This event will only be fired when an ActionController under the MyModule namespace is dispatched.
                $controller = $e->getTarget();
                $controller->layout('layout/frontlayout');
            }, 100);
        }
    */
        public function getConfig()
        {
            return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
        }
        // Add this method:
        public function getServiceConfig()
        {
            return array(
                'factories' => array(

                    'Front\Model\Cms' =>  function($sm) {
                        $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                        $table     = new \Front\Model\Cms($dbAdapter);
                        return $table;
                    },

                    'Front\Model\Slider' => function($sm) {
                        $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                        $table     = new \Front\Model\Slider($dbAdapter);
                        return $table;
                    },

                ),
            );
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Stack Trace is like this:

> Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotCreatedException

```
File: /home/projectname/public_html/dev/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:859
Message: An exception was raised while creating "Front/Model/Slider"; no instance returned

#0 /home/projectname/public_html/dev/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php(984): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createServiceViaCallback(Object(Closure), 'frontmodelslide...', 'Front/Model/Sli...')
#1 /home/projectname/public_html/dev/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php(597): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createFromFactory('frontmodelslide...', 'Front/Model/Sli...')
#2 /home/projectname/public_html/dev/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php(556): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate('Front/Model/Sli...', 'frontmodelslide...')
#3 /home/projectname/public_html/dev/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php(480): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->create(Array)
#4 /home/projectname/public_html/dev/module/Front/src/Front/Controller/FrontController.php(65): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('Front/Model/Sli...')
#5 /home/projectname/public_html/dev/module/Front/src/Front/Controller/FrontController.php(53): Front\Controller\FrontController->getSlider()
#6 /home/projectname/public_html/dev/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/AbstractActionController.php(83): Front\Controller\FrontController->indexAction()
#7 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#8 /home/projectname/public_html/dev/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#9 /home/projectname/public_html/dev/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#10 /home/projectname/public_html/dev/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/AbstractController.php(117): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#11 /home/projectname/public_html/dev/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/DispatchListener.php(114): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#12 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#13 /home/projectname/public_html/dev/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#14 /home/projectname/public_html/dev/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#15 /home/projectname/public_html/dev/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Application.php(309): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#16 /home/projectname/public_html/dev/public/index.php(17): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#17 {main}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The PDO extension is required for this adapter but the extension is not loaded

This gives you the answer: php has a module called [php data objects](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), or pdo. This is a module available on modern php installations which enables database access for your php application.

I think there are three possible reasons:

1. You don't have the pdo module installed
2. You have pdo as a module installed, but not enabled
3. You have an old version of php. For Zend Framework 2, minimally php 5.3.3 is required

So you probably have to upgrade or configure your server to get this working.

Comment: Thanks for your replay.its solved my PDO required error. but cant solve first error  Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotCreatedException

File:

/home/projectname/public_html/dev/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:859

Message:

An exception was raised while creating "Page/Model/Quality"; no instance returned

Comment: Can you explain 1) where you instantiate the model 2) how the factory looks like and 3) if there are any previous exceptions which are shown in the stack trace. Then it's easier to answer the first problem.

Comment: @Sluiman i have updated my questions please see it and give me proper answer